# Ksoap calling Webservice - Problem with SoapObject

Tags: android, web-services, ksoap

I am trying to call a `WSDL Webservice` via **Ksoap** for my Android App. When I use `SoapPrimitive`, it works and I get the following String:

```
{"INGREDIENTS": [
    {
        "TEXT": "ohne Schweinefleisch",
        "KEY": "*"
    },
    {
        "TEXT": "mit Alkohol",
        "KEY": "11"
    },
```

......

and so on.. I would like to have only the "Text" in a `ListView`, but I don't know how I can realize that with SoapPrimitive.

And when I use SoapObject, I only get the following Exeption:

```
"java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive cannot be cast to org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject"
```

Here is my Code:

```
 try {

        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.dotNet=true;
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
        }
```

What's wrong? I looked since hours in the web, but i didn't find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response looks like a `JSONArray` of `JSONObject`s. You can parse it with [built-in json library](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/package-summary.html)
or use [gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/).

Comment: ok thanks,
you mean something like this:

Object result = (Object)envelope.getResponse();
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(result.toString());

Comment: In your case it should be `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result.toString());`, but you got my point.